# How to use webkitRequestFileSystem at file: protocol

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, html5-filesystem

According to [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) at

> Browser support & storage limitations
>
> You may need the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag if you're
>   debugging your app from `file://`. Not using these flags will result
>   in a `SECURITY_ERR` or `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` FileError.

Launched chromium with `--allow-file-access-from-files` , `--unlimited-storage` and possibly deprecated `--unlimited-quota-for-files`; also `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=file:///path/to/directory/*` with `--user-data-dir=/path/to/directory` set.

Interestingly, when chromium opens a notification is displayed

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag:
>   `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`. Stability and security
>   will suffer.

There are other flags which are not specified which can be used; ignored notification as was still able to set and get `localStorage` at `file:` protocol, spcecifically files at `file:///path/to/directory/*`, though

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  console.log(grantedBytes)
}, errorHandler);
```

logged `0`, where `errorHandler` is

```
function errorHandler(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Also

```
function writeFile(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile("file.txt", {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        // call `readFile`
        window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, readFile, errorHandler);
      };
      fileWriter.onerror = errorHandler;
      var blob = new Blob(["abc"], {type: "text/plain"});
      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, writeFile, errorHandler);

function readFile(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile("file.txt", {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onloadend = function(e) {
         console.log(e.target.result)
       };
       reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}
```

logged

```
FileError {code: 7, name: "InvalidStateError", message: "An operation that depends on state cached in an in…he state had changed since it was read from disk."}
code:7
message:"An operation that depends on state cached in an interface object was made but the state had changed since it was read from disk."
name:"InvalidStateError"
__proto__:DOMError
```

Question: What are modifications necessary at launch flags, workarounds or other approaches that would allow use of `webkitRequestFileSystem` at `file:` protocol?

Comment: I did not get that error, or `0` for `grantedBytes` when testing this out. Used all the flags you listed except: `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`, `--unlimited-quota-for-files`, `--unlimited-storage`. Only change I had to make was when wanting to do persistent data had to use `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota` first.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Were you able to write to `FileSystem` at `file:` protocol? Which version of chrome or chromium? Can you post the `.html` file that you tested at `file:` protocol and `js` used at the `.html` file?

Comment: Yea, it wrote the file with `abc` inside it for the both temp and persistent. I tried it both with Chrome(50.0.2661.102 m) and Chromium (53.0.2752.0) both on Windows 10. Sure I'll edit a link in a second

Comment: [Persistent storage version](http://pastebin.com/shZwtsCx), [Temporary storage version](http://pastebin.com/LJynv6Tq), and the command line switches: `--allow-file-access-from-files --user-data-dir=/path/to/my/Desktop/data`. And was launched using file url: `file:///C:/Users/polar/Desktop/test.html`

Comment: @PatrickEvans The first version of chromium tested was user error; disk was full. Not certain why second version tested logged error. Was able to write to `FileSystem` at `file:` at third try by installing chromium 50.0.2661.102 at a live os.

Comment: @PatrickEvans May have been use of an older profile configuration folder; used a different chromium configuration folder at same version and expected result was achieved.

Answer (score 2):

The initial try received errors at `terminal` relating to lack of space on device. Received two separate errors `code 7` `InvalidStateError` and `code 3` `AbortError`. Note, chromium was launched in a sandbox at each configuration.

Was able to achieve expected result of writing to `FileSystem` at `file:` protocol by adjusting launch flags to `--allow-file-access-from-files` and specifying a different chromium configuration folder at `--user-data-dir=/newer/version/of/profile/folder`; `--unlimited-quota-for-files` and `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=file:///path/to/directory/*` were not necessary to achieve requirement.

Not entirely certain why original profile folder was using logged errors when attempting to access `FileSystem` at `file:` protocol. The folder could have been from a previous version of chromium. Generally launch new or newest version chromium from command-line where `chromium` folder in configuration directory may have been an older version with preferences already set. When reviewed `terminal` at one point `no space left on disk` message was logged in relation to `FileSystem` when launched using former profile configuration folder. Tried a newer version of chromium profile folder which solved issue.

Much credit for solution is due to @PatrickEvans for verifying that process was indeed possible; that it was more than likely a user error which was limiting realization of expected result.

```
var requestedBytes = 16,
  _grantedBytes;

function errorHandler(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

function writeFile(fs) {
  console.log(fs)
  fs.root.getFile("file.txt", {
    create: true
  }, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        // call `readFile`
        console.log(_grantedBytes);
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY
                                      , _grantedBytes
                                      , readFile
                                      , errorHandler);
      };
      fileWriter.onerror = errorHandler;
      var blob = new Blob(["abc"], {
        type: "text/plain"
      });
      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}

navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.requestQuota(requestedBytes
, function(grantedBytes) {
    console.log(grantedBytes);
    _grantedBytes = grantedBytes;
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY
                                  , grantedBytes
                                  , writeFile
                                  , errorHandler);

}, errorHandler);

function readFile(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile("file.txt", {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result, fileEntry.toURL());
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Great to see a tested functional working example. THNAKS. (Except the first two instances of console.log() have no semicolons). All worked fine other than that.