# Read local XML with JS

Tags: javascript, json, xml

At the moment, due to the [security policy Chromium](https://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html) can not read local files via ajax without `--allow-file-access-from-files`. But I currently need to create a web application where the database is a xml-file (in the extreme case, json), located in one dir with index.html. It is understood that the user can run this application locally. Are there workarounds for reading xml- (json-) file, without wrapping it in a function and change to js extension?

```
loadXMLFile('./file.xml').then(xml => {
    // working with xml
});

function loadXMLFile(filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if('ActiveXObject' in window) {
            // If is IE
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.load(filename);

            resolve(xmlDoc.xml);
        } else {
            /*
             * how to read xml file if is not IE?
             * ...
             * resolve(something);
             */
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If a cookie can't store enough data for the intended usage, how about [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: Currently i am still unclear of what you need,`load a xml/json in chrome without function via a plugin or something else?`Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar  this question about reading file rather than parsing xml

Comment: Are you trying to get `'./file.xml'` from local filesystem without launching chromium with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag? Or, are you trying to parse the returned `XML` `document` after retrieving file using `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: HTA is a simple way on windows machines, NW.JS or cordova also comes to mind

Answer (score 4):

Accessing `file:` protocol at chromium using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `<link>` element without `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set at chromium instance launch is not enabled by default.

[`--allow-file-access-from-files`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files)

> By default, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. This is an
>   override for developers who need the old behavior for testing.

---

> At the moment, due to the security policy Chromium can not read local
>   files via ajax without `--allow-file-access-from-files`. But I
>   currently need to create a web application where the database is a
>   xml-file (in the extreme case, json), located in one dir with
>   index.html. It is understood that the user can run this application
>   locally. Are there workarounds for reading xml- (json-) file, without
>   wrapping it in a function and change to js extension?

If user is aware that local files are to be used by the application you can utilize `<input type="file">` element for user to upload file from user local filesystem, process file using `FileReader`, then proceed with application.

Else, advise user that use of application requires launching chromium with  `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set, which can be done by creating a launcher for this purpose, specifying a different user data directory for the instance of chromium. The launcher could be, for example

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --user-data-dir="/home/user/.config/chromium-temp" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

See also [How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent)

The above command could also be run at `terminal`

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser --user-data-dir="/home/user/.config/chromium-temp" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

without creating a desktop launcher; where when the instance of chromium is closed run

```
$ rm -rf /home/user/.config/chromium-temp
```

to remove the configuration folder for the instance of chromium.

Once the flag is set, user can include `<link>` element with `rel="import"` attribute and `href` pointing to local file and `type` set to `"application/xml"`, for option other than `XMLHttpRequest` to get file. Access `XML` `document` using

```
const doc = document.querySelector("link[rel=import]").import;
```

See [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824927/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-link-script-is-still-pending-or-has-it-failed/).

---

Another alternative, though more involved, would be to use `requestFileSystem` to to store the file at `LocalFileSystem`.

See

- [How to use webkitRequestFileSystem at file: protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502091/how-to-use-webkitrequestfilesystem-at-file-protocol)
- [jQuery File Upload Plugin: Is possible to preserve the structure of uploaded folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/)
- [How to Write in file (user directory) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098129/how-to-write-in-file-user-directory-using-javascript/)

Or create or modify a chrome app and use

```
chrome.fileSystem
```

See [GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/filesystem-access](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access).

---

The simplest approach would be to provide a means for file upload by affirmative user action; process the uploaded file, then proceed with the application.

```js
const reader = new FileReader;

const parser = new DOMParser;

const startApp = function startApp(xml) {
  return Promise.resolve(xml || doc)
};

const fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileupload");

const label = document.querySelector("label[for=fileupload]");

const handleAppStart = function handleStartApp(xml) {
  console.log("xml document:", xml);
  label.innerHTML = currentFileName + " successfully uploaded";
  // do app stuff
}

const handleError = function handleError(err) {
  console.error(err)
}

let doc;
let currentFileName;

reader.addEventListener("loadend", handleFileRead);

reader.addEventListener("error", handleError);

function handleFileRead(event) {
  label.innerHTML = "";
  currentFileName = "";
  try {
    doc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, "application/xml");
    fileUpload.value = "";

    startApp(doc)
    .then(function(data) {
        handleAppStart(data)
    })
    .catch(handleError);
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
  }
}

function handleFileUpload(event) {
  let file = fileUpload.files[0];
  if (/xml/.test(file.type)) {
    reader.readAsText(file);
    currentFileName = file.name;
  }
}

fileUpload.addEventListener("change", handleFileUpload)
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" accept=".xml" />
<label for="fileupload"></label>
```

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz See also [Set Up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow).

Answer (score 1):

use `document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null)`

instead of `new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')`.

You can find the API through GOOGLE. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the deliverable is intended to run locally so you will not be able to set any flags for local file access on a user's machine. Something I've done in a pinch is to pack it up as an executable with something like [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) and keep the external data files. Otherwise, you're probably looking at loading as script using a JSON schema in a JS file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. I solved by simply embedding the XML file into the HTML using PHP. Since the application is loaded locally from disk, size, cache etc. are not a concern.

If you're using Webpack, you can instead directly import the file using a loader like [this](https://github.com/gisikw/xml-loader) or [this](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader), in which case the file is included into the resulting bundled javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can load XML through a string of text using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), Just load your file and parse the text using the `.parseFromString`. You could use an if statement containing `(window.DOMParser)` to check if the DOMParser is supported