# How to read hardcoded image file using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it  possible to use hardcoded filename?

I want to read File of an image.

I have hardcoded filename like, '/Users/Desktop/1.jpg' and i want to use this
as a file.

I want to change this '/Users/Desktop/1.jpg' type as file.

```
var imageURL = '/Users/Desktop/1.jpg';

new File(imageURL);

alert(typeof(imageURL));  // I want this as a File
```

Comment: Can you include further details of what you are trying to accomplish at Question?

Comment: I just use this in extend javascript, var img=new File('1.jpg''); Its create a file. but i want to use this in javascript / jquery

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to click or drag and drop the file at an `<input type="file">` element.

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
<script>
  const input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.onchange = function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
  }
</script>
```

If the file is served with CORS headers you can request the file using `Image` constructor and pass the `<img>` reference to `canvas.toBlob()`, then pass `Blob` reference to `File` constructor, optionally set the name of the `File` object.

Similarly CORS headers are necessary when using `fetch()` and `Response.blob()` to get `Blob` of image.

Note if using Chrome or Chromium browser to request files at local filesystem you can launch Chrome or Chromium browsers with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to access local filesystem at JavaScript and HTML, see [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js).

Comment: But i want to use the local file dynamically. In this approach, file is selected by user.I have ask its alternate solution. pls refer how to set a value on input type file dynamically.

Comment: It is only possible to set the `.files` property to a `FileList` object, for example, using drag and drop. Else use `new Image()` or `fetch()` to request the file