# cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com not working (503). What else can I try?

Tags: javascript, angular, heroku, cors, cors-anywhere

I am trying to send a get request to the Wikipedia API.  I am sending the request form a angular frontend so i'm trying to use the Heroku CORS Anywhere endpoint to avoid CORS issues.  For some reason, I'm still getting a 503 response saying no access-control-allow-origin header is present on the requested resource.  Any idea why this would happen/what else I can try?

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';



@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    API_URL: string = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getRandomArticle() : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}Special:Random`)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((err: any) => Observable.throw(err || 'server error'));
  }

}
```

Comment: About Wikipedia in particular, you know that just by adding `origin=*` to the query parameters for a Wikipedia API URL, you can actually make cross-origin requests to Wikipedia work? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106041/does-wikipedia-api-support-cors-or-only-jsonp-available/37109743#37109743

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can deploy a *CORS Anywhere* server to Heroku in just 2-3 minutes, with 5 commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
cd cors-anywhere/
npm install
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

After running those commands, you’ll end up with your own *CORS Anywhere* proxy running at, e.g. `https://cryptic-headland-94862.herokuapp.com/`. So then instead of prefixing your request URL with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`, prefix it with your proxy’s URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  I think this is the most perfect/comprehensive answer i've ever received on here...

Comment: How do you use this proxy to whitelist your own domain?

Comment: And for those without `heroku` yet installed run this in your terminal (on a Mac, untested on other machines): `brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku` - it may take a few minutes to complete

Comment: Additionally I had to `npm install heroku` before `heroku create` which after installation opened a browser where I had to create an account.

Comment: Heroku free tier is not available anymore.. there's any other free option to set this 'cors-anywhere' server?

Comment: This option costs money after a certain amount of requests.

Answer (score 1):

In response to this I wanted to give a more detailed response for Windows users:

**Windows Requried Items**

- Create Heroku account (heroku.com) Install the Heroku CLI (e.g.
  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line) Install
  Git (e.g. https://gitforwindows.org/) Install npm tools (e.g.
  https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

**After everything above is done, issue the following commands**

Open a new terminal, then:

```
heroku login
git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
cd cors-anywhere/
npm install
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

It will process and update/upload and you will get a app URL:

```
https://some-name-giveng.herokuapp.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the public demo server (cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com) is limited by January 2021 https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301

**Here is my own proxy server**

https://fast-dawn-89938.herokuapp.com/

You can use like: https://fast-dawn-89938.herokuapp.com/https://your-domain.com

**demo:** https://fast-dawn-89938.herokuapp.com/https://google.com

Comment: this is not working again.

Comment: I have fixed it. plz check now