# Same Origin Policy easily circumvented?

Tags: security, browser, cors, xss, same-origin-policy

I've read an article which used [Cors-Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) to make an example url request, and it made me think about how easily the Same Origin Policy can be bypassed.

While the browser prevents you from accessing the error directly, and cancels the request altogether when it doesn't pass a preflight request, a simple node server does not need to abide to such rules, and can be used as a proxy.

All there needs to be done is to append `'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'` to the start of the requested url in the malicious script and Voila, you don't need to pass CORS.

And as [sideshowbarker pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085173/5677209), it takes a couple of minutes to deploy your own Cors-Anywhere server.

Doesn't it make SOP as a security measure pretty much pointless?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the SOP is to segregate data stored in browsers by their origin. If you got a cookie from domain1.tld (or it stored data for you in a browser store), Javascript on domain2.tld will not be able to gain access. This cannot be circumvented by any server-side component, because that component will still not have access in any way. If there was no SOP, a malicious site could just read any data stored by other websites in your browsers.

Now this is also related to CORS, as you somewhat correctly pointed out. Normally, your browser will not receive the response from a javascript request made to a different origin than the page origin it's running on. The purpose of this is that if it worked, you could gain information from sites where the user is logged in. If you send it through Cors-Anywhere though, you will not be able to send the user's session cookie for the other site, because you still don't have access, the request goes to your own server as the proxy.

Where Cors-Anywhere matters is unauthenticated APIs. Some APIs might check the origin header and only respond to their own client domain. In that case, sure, Cors-Anywhere can add or change CORS headers so that you can query it from your own hosted client. But the purpose of SOP is not to prevent this, and even in this case, it would be a lot easier for the API owner to blacklist or throttle your requests, because they are all proxied by your server.

So in short, SOP and CORS are not access control mechanisms in the sense I think you meant. Their purpose is to prevent and/or securely allow cross-origin requests to certain resources, but they are not meant to for example prevent server-side components from making any request, or for example to try and authenticate your client javascript itself (which is not technically possible).