# Cordova Media Capture - JS File.copyFile function?

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, media

I am having trouble with [Cordova Media Capture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#capturecapturevideo) where I get an error saying:

[image]

This happens after I take a video and try to display it.  The video player seems to record fine but the file doesn't play.  I looked in the console and found the above error.

I found a solution that I think will work:

http://www.agiliztech.com/2017/06/29/retrieve-audio-video-file-ionic-2-app/

but in the code he has a line that says File.copyFile().  I don't know what library this is coming from.  Does anyone know?

[image]

Also, does anyone know the root cause of my problem?  Or is there a JS alternative to what he is doing that I can use if you don't know what File.copyFile is?

I am currently getting the error File.copyFile is not a function - Which it's not a function...

Thanks.

Comment: At which browser are you trying code?

Comment: I'm making a WebApp, i'm trying to get it to work on Android.  But I am inspecting it using Chrome

Comment: Chrome, Chromium does not allow access to `file:` protocol by default, see [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)

Comment: So I would need to test this on Chromium instead of Chrome and change the defaults of my Chromium browser to allow access to the file: protocol?  Would the users of my app get this problem?  Would the tutorial above not work?

Comment: Chrome is built using Chromium source code. You can adjust launcher to `Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` for local testing.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that thanks

Comment: According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode that flag is dangerous.  I did an npm install on http-server then did a http-server -p 8100 to start up the server.  Then I opened another command prompt and did an ionic run android.  It still doesn't work.  The ports match.  Did I do this right?

Comment: Do you mean according to one answer at the linked Question? The flag can  used for local development.

Comment: I don't think i'm understanding this.  I cd'd to the folder containing my Chrome.exe and ran "chrome --allow-file-access-from-files".  This opened up a new chrome browser which looks the same as before.  I am using this URL to see the errors in my device: chrome://inspect/#devices.  So I put that URL into the new opened browser hit inspect however, I still receive the same error.

Comment: This was following my link as I was confused at what 'usr' was all about.  My terminal could not find that folder

Comment: Did you have an open instance of Chrome running when you launched using flag? If yes, Chrome will launch using the existing running instance folder if `--user-data-dir` flag is not set to a different configuration folder. Or close all open instances of Chrome and launch using `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set.

Comment: Wow that actually worked - Looks incredible Thanks!