# How to play music from local folder in html audio control?

Tags: html

Here is the audio control.  When I put the path in browser nothing is showing.

```
    <audio  controls="controls">
        <source src="E:/Songs/ROCK ON2/Rock On 2/You Know What I Mean(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3" />
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to url encode your file path.  It doesn't know what to do with the spaces in your file name.  So either [encode it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or remove all the spaces from every part of that path.

Comment: If I remove the spaces from the path, the path will be changed.

Comment: Well, yes.  That's exactly what I'm saying here.  You need to conform that path somehow, either by hand or using `encodeURI`.

Comment: I have given  src="E:/Lean On-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3" which is the correct path.But still it is unable to play the song. And how to use encodeURI??

Comment: Check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to play local files you can use `<input type="file">` to get file as a `File` object and create a `Blob URL` of file to set at `.src` of `<audio>` element at `change` event of `<input type="file">` element.

```html
<input type="file">
<audio controls></audio>
<script>
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
input.onchange = function() {
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I have a list of songs with full path.So I want that when I will click on any song the audio control should play the song.

Comment: At which browser are you trying code?

Comment: You are not getting my point. I don't want to select a file through fileupload.I want to play directly.

Comment: @Swadesh _"You are not getting my point."_ You did not answer the question at previous comment. At which browser are you trying code?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: See [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)