# W1Temp with ds18b20 using Javascript on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, requirejs

I'm making a js-based clock on a Raspberry Pi. It runs in chromium & displays the time & weather (using `simpleWeather`). I've connected a `ds18b20` and I want to display the temperature too. The device is working, I can read the temperature from the command line but I want to read it and display it in my js script.

I'm using `w1temp`. I'm getting the require part wrong and not managing to load w1temp properly, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I'm using require like this:

```
require(['../../node_modules/w1temp'], function (W1Temp) { 
});
```

Then

```
setInterval( function () {
     W1Temp.getSensor('28-0414609d26ff').then(function (sensor) {
        // get inside temperature
        var temp = sensor.getTemperature();
        $("#inside_temp").html(temp);
     });
},1000);
```

In doing this I get a js error when I load the page & my temperature isn't displayed. The error is:

> Not allowed to load local resource: `home/pi/node_modules/w1temp.js`

I guess this is because their isn't a `home/pi/node_modules/w1temp.js`, but what do I require to get the temp out of w1temp?

I know I'm making a simple error based on a simple misunderstanding, & I've read the w1temp docs but I can't see where I'm going wrong. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: See [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)

Answer (score 0):

The npm package **[ds18x20](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ds18x20)** worked well. You can use either synchronous or asynchronous loading:

```
var sensor = require('ds18x20');

  sensor.getAll(function (err, tempObj) {
  console.log(tempObj); // will display temperature using the asynchronous method
});

var tempObj = sensor.getAll();
  console.log(tempObj); // will display temperature using the synchronous method
```

I tried several other npm packages, but this one was the easiest to work with and it helped tremendously.