# Id tag causes audio to not play in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I have an audio element on a webpage and I need to add an id tag "player" to the element. I am using getElementById("player").

The element in quesiton:

```
<audio id="player" controls loop>
     <source src="Out_of_the_Skies_Under_the_Earth.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

I am using the 'player' tag to make the next two lines useful, using the Web Audio API:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('player');
var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);
```

This is the only place I am using the id 'player,' and I am open to any alternatives.

When I add the id tag the audio does not play in Chrome (it will play without the tag). It will play fine in Safari and Opera but not Chrome. I have tried bouncing the file to a smaller bit/sample rate, using .ogg, using getElementByClassName instead, but nothing seems to be working.

EDIT:
Also, I'd like to note that the player does show the correct length of the audio file (6:03) and it shows the progress bar moving and the time updating correctly. It's just as if the sound is muted.

This snippet isn't necessarily the exact problem I was having since my audio file is local.

*Since posting this I have noticed that I get the error: 'MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for [local file]' I think that hosting the file under my own domain with the required CORS header might fix the issue. I don't have time to implement this right now but I will update the post my solution in the answers below.*

But in the mean time, any suggestions would be great.

```js
var ctx = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new ctx();

var mediaElement = document.getElementById('player');
var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);

// create the equalizer. It's a set of biquad Filters

var filters = [];

    // Set filters
    [60, 170, 350, 1000, 3500, 10000].forEach(function(freq, i) {
      var eq = context.createBiquadFilter();
      eq.frequency.value = freq;
      eq.type = "peaking";
      eq.gain.value = 0;
      filters.push(eq);
    });

 // Connect filters in serie
   sourceNode.connect(filters[0]);
   for(var i = 0; i < filters.length - 1; i++) {
      filters[i].connect(filters[i+1]);
    }

// connect the last filter to the speakers
filters[filters.length - 1].connect(context.destination);

function changeGain(sliderVal,nbFilter) {
  var value = parseFloat(sliderVal);
  filters[nbFilter].gain.value = value;

  // update output labels
  var output = document.querySelector("#gain"+nbFilter);
  output.value = value + " dB";
}
```

```css
div audio {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.eq {
  margin: 32px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color:lightGrey;
  padding:10px;
  width:300px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 12px;
}


div.controls:hover {
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
}
div.controls label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

div.controls label, div.controls input, output {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   font-family: "Open Sans",Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Equalizer with Bi-Quad Filters</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="eq">
  <audio id="player" controls crossorigin="anonymous" loop>
  <source src="https://vocaroo.com/i/s1lfs67BmoTC">

</audio>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>60Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 0);"></input>
  <output id="gain0">0 dB</output>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>170Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 1);"></input>
<output id="gain1">0 dB</output>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>350Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 2);"></input>
<output id="gain2">0 dB</output>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>1000Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 3);"></input>
<output id="gain3">0 dB</output>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>3500Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 4);"></input>
<output id="gain4">0 dB</output>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label>10000Hz</label>
    <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 5);"></input>
<output id="gain5">0 dB</output>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any CORS access restriction errors logged at `console`?

Comment: Yes there are, I just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL set at `<source>` element `src` attribute is not served with CORS headers and is not an `.mp3` file.

To avoid

```
MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for <URL>
```

error, you can use `fetch()`, `Body.blob()` to fetch a resource which is served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, `URL.createObjectURL()` to convert the `Blob` to a `Blob URL`, then set the `<audio>` element `src` to the `Blob URL`.

Note also that `<input>` tag is self-closing; and `filters` should be defined globally.

```js
var ctx = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new ctx();
var url = "https://ia600305.us.archive.org/30/items/return_201605/return.mp3";

var filters = [];

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById('player');
    mediaElement.src = blobURL;
    var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);

    // create the equalizer. It's a set of biquad Filters
    // Set filters
    [60, 170, 350, 1000, 3500, 10000].forEach(function(freq, i) {
      var eq = context.createBiquadFilter();
      eq.frequency.value = freq;
      eq.type = "peaking";
      eq.gain.value = 0;
      filters.push(eq);
    });

    // Connect filters in serie
    sourceNode.connect(filters[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length - 1; i++) {
      filters[i].connect(filters[i + 1]);
    }

    // connect the last filter to the speakers
    filters[filters.length - 1].connect(context.destination);

  });

function changeGain(sliderVal, nbFilter) {
  var value = parseFloat(sliderVal);
  filters[nbFilter].gain.value = value;

  // update output labels
  var output = document.querySelector("#gain" + nbFilter);
  output.value = value + " dB";
}
```

```css
div audio {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.eq {
  margin: 32px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 12px;
}

div.controls:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.controls label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

div.controls label,
div.controls input,
output {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Equalizer with Bi-Quad Filters</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="eq">
      <audio id="player" controls crossorigin="anonymous" loop></audio>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>60Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 0);">
        <output id="gain0">0 dB</output>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>170Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 1);">
        <output id="gain1">0 dB</output>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>350Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 2);">
        <output id="gain2">0 dB</output>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>1000Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 3);">
        <output id="gain3">0 dB</output>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>3500Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 4);">
        <output id="gain4">0 dB</output>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label>10000Hz</label>
        <input type="range" value="0" step="1" min="-30" max="30" oninput="changeGain(this.value, 5);">
        <output id="gain5">0 dB</output>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: @AvaD Note, `fetch()` and `URL.createObjectURL()` are not necessary to achieve expected result. The file needs to be served with CORS headers, or launch Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` header or use `<input type="file">` element to test the code locally, see [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)