# How to play audio with specific decibels/frequency in React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, android, audio, react-native, decibel

I need to reproduce an audio/beep in a specific intensity (decibels/dB) and frequency (hertz/hZ). I've looked at these react libraries:

- https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound
- https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit

But none of these handles the volume in that way (the volume is set in range [0,1] from silence to full volume), and doesn't have an option to define frequency.

So, is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Comment: You won't be able to specify decibels output on any device where the user can turn the volume up or down, which is why it ranges from 0-1 (0 being silent and 1 being what the user has chosen their volume level to be at).  Plus, all devices will have different speakers so there is no standard volume for devices, by which to specify decibels.

Comment: See [Id tag causes audio to not play in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370887/id-tag-causes-audio-to-not-play-in-chrome/)

Comment: Did you figure out how to produce a specific frequency?