# Read Json file into a variable

Tags: javascript, json, file

I want to read a JSON file into a variable. My JSON file would be named "questions.json" and will have this type of content:

```
{
      question: "Question 1?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Question 2?",
      answers: {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "The Correct One"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
}
```

I have tried many things to work this out, such as: loadStrings and then parse the string as a JSON type (told me that loadStrings is undefined), really everything i found on the web with reading local files in javascript and nothign really worked..

Comment: That's not JSON. "Nothing really worked" is not a problem description. Is your code part of a web page? How are you running your code?

Comment: Have you looked up NodeJS ? Filesystems in NodeJS?

Comment: @melpomene I am running my code in a ```script.js``` file that i attached on my html and css webpage

Comment: OK, so it's running in a browser. Where is this JSON file located, on your web server or on the client machine (where the browser runs)?

Comment: First, I wanted to test it locally in the same folder, but it would probably run on some webserver

Comment: JavaScript code runs on the client. It cannot access files on some other machine (such as the web server). It can only send HTTP requests.

Comment: See [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js)

Comment: @melpomene okay, then if so, I somehow manage to get this "JSON file" somewhere on the web to receive and HTTP request and let javascript take that file, how would that be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question raised there:
[Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)
if you are using jquery, check the answer there, also reported here:

```
$.getJSON("questions.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

If you are just using javascript, check answer from xgqfrms using:

new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: i'm using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fetch api:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

[There is a polyfill for older browsers](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: and what if my json file was from github what would I need to do extra? and what if I wanted to store that in a variable?